# Need help to create this flutter animation

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I need help to create this loading animation and integrate it into my flutter application. I am pretty new to flutter and still learning it, so any help will be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Can you include what you've tried so far?

Comment: you can check rive animation

Comment: @Nakul Bisht To create animation use this https://lottiefiles.com/
and to use created animation in flutter use this https://pub.dev/packages/lottie

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Rive](https://rive.app/) to create this animation, and deploy it into your Flutter Application.